# How Can We Close NSFileManager?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, nsfilemanager

In my ios application, I use a lot of images(about one thousand) to show info about products. Then i got an error like this in run time;

> ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed 
>   error = 24 (Too many open files)

How can i close the opened files?And I am using NSFileManager.

Thank you for your answer.

UPDATE:

some codes from my viewdidload,

```
while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)  {
                    NSString *imageName= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
                    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

                    NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
                    if (pngData == nil) {
                        image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"resimYok.jpeg"];//horoda
                    }else{
                        image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
                    }
                    image2=[image2 imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(175, 210)];

                    UIButton * urunDetayButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                    [urunDetayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(column*197+38 , row*350+58, 159, 170)];
                    [urunDetayButton setImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [urunDetayButton addTarget:self
                                        action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
                              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    urunDetayButton.tag = UrunId;
                    [scrollView addSubview:urunDetayButton];

                    UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(column*197+30, row*350, 175, 280)];
                    UIImage *blackBackGround = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BackImage.png"];
                    [background setImage:blackBackGround];                                            
                    [scrollView addSubview:background];
                    [background release];
                    [blackBackGround release];

                    UIImage *sepeteEkleButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sepeteEkleButtonImage.png"];
                    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(column*197+38 , row*350+8, 159, 45)];
                    [button setImage:sepeteEkleButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [button addTarget:self
                               action:@selector(addToChart:)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    button.tag = UrunId;

                    [sepeteEkleButtonImage release];
                }
```

in this loop, i create thousands of buttons. But i can not see some button's and some imageview's image. For example, "background" and "button" imageviews and buttons. There are two screenshots, thats must be and to be.

[image: this one must be i want]
[image: this one is current state]

Comment: how are you showing the images or opening those images?

Comment: Where do you update imageName variable: NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName]; It seems like you always get the wrong filePath... I guess you forgot to take it from db

Comment: not like that, i update my question again.

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to re-invent the wheel. If you app will be iOS 6 and newer, then look into Apple's UICollectionView. If you are going to support older iOS versions then look into  open source AQGridView. The pattern in this scenario is not to pre-populate all buttons, but to only setup the ones being displayed, just like UITableView does.

Answer (score 0):

May be it would be better to create your images with next syntax:

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: My button's images is not dissapper when my app is running and i am using the storyboard for set the image to buttons, so i didnt use this code block

Comment: What are you mean? Explain please what you are doing in more details in your question

Comment: i am using storyboard for create buttons and imageviews.And i am setting some images for this buttons and imageviews, then i am taking this error and i cant see the images on my button and imageview

Comment: >>setting some images for this buttons and imageviews - how are you doing this? When are you using NSFileManager? [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:] - creates image, not view.

Comment: i updated my question, i hope you can understand now what i am saying.